# Different Result in phone and Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I try layout in xml and run in on debugging on my phone is different, you can see the left one is a screenshot and my phone and the right one is my layout in android studio.My phone is 720 x 1520 with 6.22 inch

[Layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idBHR.png)

I use constraint layout and wrap content, I also already customise xml size and make it same with my phone size by Generic phone but I got a different result and a few layout get cut out.
Here is my code:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:context=".Activity1">


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivfoto"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="181dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="108dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etnamabelakang"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnpilih"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="@string/pilihgamber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivfoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivfoto" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnpilih"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="@string/pilihgamber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivfoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivfoto" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Pilihartis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/PilihGenre"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etpassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnpilih" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etnamadepan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:hint="@string/namadepan"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etnamabelakang"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="@string/namabelakang"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etnamadepan"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etnamadepan"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etasalnegara"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="@string/asalnegara"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etnamabelakang"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etnamabelakang"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etumur"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="@string/Umur"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etpassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etpassword"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etemail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etasalnegara"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etasalnegara"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/Pass2"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etemail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etemail"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,TextFields" />


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Pilihartis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/PilihGenre"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etpassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnpilih" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnback"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="568dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="@string/backbutton"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnregis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="568dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
    android:text="@string/register"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sppilihanmusic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:entries="@array/PilihanMusic"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Pilihartis"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Pilihartis" />

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sptanggal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:entries="@array/Pilihtanggal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etumur"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etumur" />

   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sppilihbulan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:entries="@array/PilihBulan"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sptanggal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sppilihanmusic" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the layout, the stuff on the left side? Email, password etc. It looks like those are too wide, so there's no way it will all fit on a smaller screen

Comment: i try copy a few thing,i am scared if i write it in here it will become to long,

Comment: Nah it's better if you include everything, the info is important! I'll write an answer in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I pasted your layout in, and here's how it looks on a Pixel 3 (1280 x 2160 - I feel like your Vivo Y91 image isn't set up right, it has more space in the layout designer!):

[image: blueprint view of the layout]

I've added a 380dp-wide view at the top, which basically fills the entire width. So you have just under 400dp of horizontal space to work with.

The short version: you're using `wrap_content` for your `EditText`s, but the size of that content is being set by a few things:

- the length of your `hint` text (e.g. *Nama Belakang*)
- the `ems` value which sets a width relative to the font size (the *email* and *password* boxes)
- whatever `@dimen/textSize` is set to (if it's a value in `sp`, which it should be, the text will scale with the user's settings - if they're using "Huge" text, it will be bigger and take up more space!)

That locks in the size of the boxes on the left, takes up space, and pushes the stuff on the right further away. If you don't have space for it, it will be pushed off the screen, like in the image.

Your image is 145dp wide, plus that 108dp margin on the left (between the image and the `etnamabelakang` text box). If you reduce that margin, it will fit, but on a smaller screen or with bigger text boxes it might not.

---

If I were you, I would:

- set a fixed limit on how wide the stuff on the left can be
- lock the right side of the image to the right side of the screen
- lock the left side of the image to the widest element on the left, then you can centre it

you can let the text boxes scroll if there isn't room to display the whole text - I mean if there isn't space, you need to compromise, right? And it's better to have small text boxes than parts of the UI pushed off the screen on smaller displays. If that's not acceptable, you might need to rethink your layout. Don't you just love UI work?!

---

I made some quick changes to a few things to show you something you could do (also I broke all the strings)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
tools:context=".Activity1">

<view
    android:id="@+id/this_is_380dp_wide"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivfoto"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="181dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnpilih"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="pilihgamber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivfoto"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivfoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivfoto" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etnamadepan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="150sp"
    android:hint="namadepan"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etnamabelakang"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:maxWidth="150sp"
    android:hint="namabelakang"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etnamadepan"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etnamadepan"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etasalnegara"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:maxWidth="150sp"
    android:hint="asalnegara"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etnamabelakang"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etnamabelakang"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etumur"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="Umur"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etpassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etpassword"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etemail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etasalnegara"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etasalnegara"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etpassword"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="Pass2"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etemail"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etemail"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,TextFields" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Pilihartis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="PilihGenre"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnpilih" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnback"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="568dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="backbutton"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnregis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="568dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="register"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnback"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sppilihanmusic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:entries="@array/PilihanMusic"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Pilihartis" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sptanggal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:entries="@array/Pilihtanggal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etumur"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etumur" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sppilihbulan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:entries="@array/PilihBulan"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sptanggal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sppilihanmusic" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="173dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's basically:

- made a `Guideline` to separate the two sides, with the views on either side constrained to it. You can move it around to wherever looks right.
- The `ImageView` is constrained to the guideline and the right side of the screen, and centred. I constrained the `Button` underneath to that, the other stuff below is centred between the guideline/parent - whichever works for you!
- Your top 3 text fields are all different lengths, based on the hint - I set a `maxWidth` on those (in `sp`) so they won't cross the guideline if you add a longer hint, but it won't work on smaller screens and you'd be better copying the email one - constrained to the guideline, filling the space
- I constrained your button at the bottom to the left of the other one, instead of using a bigger margin to offset it more from the parent

Looks like this on a 480x800 phone:

[image: modified layout on a small screen]

(see what I mean about the `maxWidth` not working on smaller screens, the other fields are ok though! Also notice the 380dp view doesn't fit on screen anymore, but the layout still works)

ok that was a big response, I hope some of it helps!

Comment: Sorry late for saying thanks,Now i really for understanding it and it need 2 days by using your answer,I really grateful !!! :))))))

Comment: No problem, glad it helps!

Comment: Cause i am really amateur how UI/UX designer make their layout became perfect for all devices,are they make the layout one by one?

Comment: It's hard, but google "responsive layout" to see the general idea. ``ConstraintLayout`` lets you position things relative to other things, so it all moves as the space grows or shrinks. But if it gets too small, you'll need a new layout! Try this if you have time: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0